# DatePicker: Getting error trying to set a date

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datepicker

```js
$('#item_lrec').datepicker('setDate', "03/06/2018");
```

```html
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>   
<script src="js/jquery_ui_1.12.1.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<html>
<body>
<div class="form-group"  style="float:right; width:35%">
  <label style="float:right;">Last receipt</label>
  <input name="item_lrec" id="item_lrec" class="form-control" type="text" style="float:right">        
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to set the datepicker reading the value from the database but, it doesn't working and I getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: local.getTime is not a function

why??? Where's the error???

Comment: You're including both jQuery UI and the Bootstrap Datepicker plugin, which means you have two jQuery functions called datepicker - which one are you trying to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using the [Bootstrap setDate](http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/methods.html#setdate), which takes a Date object and you are giving it a String so it tries to call a function on the string that isn't meant for a String (its meant for a Date object)

Changing the line to the below should work for you

```
$('#item_lrec').datepicker('setDate', new Date("03/06/2018"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using jQueryUI, the format for setDate is listed here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate

Without seeing the rest of your code, I'm *guessing* that `data.data.item_lrec` is not formatted correctly, it should be in "MM/DD/YYYY" format, ex "05/24/2018".

Comment: If you post a larger example of your code we can help, but just looking at one line doesn't give people enough information to know what's going on. To narrow down the problem, try using setDate with a static value, ex:
`$('#item_lrec').datepicker('setDate', "04/16/2018")`
And see if that works?

Comment: ok I posted a part of my code. I checked the value in the variable and it is correct! I really don't have idea how can I fix it

Comment: Glad that you got it fixed! :) Next time you post a question, be sure to post full code along with it, and/or mention which script you're using. (I assumed you were using jQuery UI's datepicker whereas you're actually using a Bootstrap plugin.)

Comment: sure I will!! Thanks anyway